# Populating and Fetching Core Data One to Many Networked JSON Objects using Generic Method

Tags: ios, json, networking, core-data, one-to-many

I have two entities, entity 1:Categories and entity 2"Companies which have a one-to-many relationship.

The data for each is downloaded using a NSURLSession. The JSON objects in the categories entity have an array of all the ids of the companies and the company JSON object has the id of its category.

I have created a generic method where the JSON attribute names match that of the entity attributes, so they will be added automatically.

I know since there is an inverse relationship, any data added in one entity will be reflected in both entity objects. But my question is which should I add first? I mean if I add the categories, then I will have to create objects of companies which have only ids and then I will have to create an NSpredicate when adding any company and check whether the id exists and add the remaining data.

The problem is I don't know how to incorporate this in my generic method and I'm wondering is there another way to do this? I don't want to use MagicalRecord as I'm trying to understand the concepts.

```
- (void) addDataToEntity:(NSArray *)jasonArrayData : (NSNumber *) entitySpecifier{

    //Flag to determine entity name
    NSString *entityName;

    if([entitySpecifier isEqual:@2]){
        entityName = @"Categories";

    }else if ([entitySpecifier isEqual:@3]){
        entityName = @"Companies";
    }

    //get entity
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.elRehabCoreData.managedObjectContext];

    //get attributes of entity in core data
    NSDictionary *attributes = [entity attributesByName];


    for (NSDictionary *keyedValues in jasonArrayData) {

        //loop over entities in core data
        for (NSString *attribute in attributes) {
            id value = [keyedValues objectForKey:attribute];

            if (value == nil) {
                // Don't attempt to set nil, or you'll overwite values in self that aren't present in keyedValues
                continue;
            }
            NSAttributeType attributeType = [[attributes objectForKey:attribute] attributeType];

            if ((attributeType == NSStringAttributeType) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])) {
                value = [value stringValue];
            } else if (((attributeType == NSInteger16AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSInteger32AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSInteger64AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSBooleanAttributeType)) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
                value = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[value integerValue]];
            } else if ((attributeType == NSFloatAttributeType) &&  ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
                value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[value doubleValue]];
            }


            //add values for valid attribute

           if([entitySpecifier isEqual:@2]){
                Categories *category = (Categories *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];

                [category setValue:value forKey:attribute];
                [self.elRehabCoreData.managedObjectContext insertObject:category];

            }else if ([entitySpecifier isEqual:@3]){
                Companies *company = (Companies *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
                [company setValue:value forKey:attribute];
                [self.elRehabCoreData.managedObjectContext insertObject:company];
            }


        }

    }
}
```

And the Data Model looks like this: 
[image]

Comment: This confused me which made me wonder about the data model.

Comment: This confused me which made me wonder about the data model.  Thinking that through I feel that "categories" should really be an attribute of a company.  The purpose of having categories would be to group the companies together but that can be done via query on that attribute.  Also you said it was a one to many which tells me that each company has a single category.  Even if it grew to multiple categories per company this could be an array object for the attribute and would be easy to manage than a many to many relationship.

Comment: I have added the data model. I mistakenly added in the the tags, many - to- many, I meant one to many.
Categories is indeed an attribute of a Company in my JSON.
So your saying its better that I remove the relationship of companies in the categories entity and just have an attribute in the company entity, so I can manage the models?
Also I have another entity which has a many to many relationship with the companies, how would I incorporate the relationship in my generic method?  
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for adding the picture.  That helps a lot.  With all the attributes you have assigned to Categories I see that you will save space having that remain it's own entity.  I retract my though of adding category as a company attribute.  I would create the category data set first.  It doesn't have to point to any companies initially.   Then when you create the compnay entries you will simply point them to the appropriate category.  The system will essentially build the reverse link for you.

Comment: You should also look to change the plural references.  Your entities should be named in singular form - Company and Category, not companies and categories.  The relationship in Category should be companies as it points to multiple instances of a company

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it, will do what you said and if it works, I'll post the answer. Thanks again.